# How can one create a complete block in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, content-type

I Couldn't find anything on this so maybe you guys could give me some clues if this is possible using JavaScript or not.

Like the question asks, how can I pop an entire block into my html with just using SJ or maybe JQuery?

No not just a div saying Hello and with pretty colors and stuff but an entire block. Meaning a Div with actual content like forms, buttons, spans, links, images and other stuff.

I wanted a temporary popup that wouldn't save data and make the entire project really heavy but instead just appear with some preset values that's called by a JSON script.
Like a temporary form of some sorts.

Comment: You could use dull colors, and the stuff you need instead of "Hello" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you are describing is pretty common use of Javascript so it is strange that you did not find anything about it. 
There are entire sites written on pure Javascript.

Nevertheless , for a out-of-the-box solution to your inquiry , there is a really good plugin , check it out here : http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/.

If you want to learn how to do it yourself , then you should read on the Javascript DOM manipulation functions like :

- Node.removeChild()
- Node.replaceChild()
- Node.insertBefore()
- Node.hasChildNodes()

Start from "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild" and go on.

Comment: i did not get you at all :/ I wanted an example where the JS creates an entire floating div with an id, classname, content like a form. So trying to figure it out like that would take too much time. i'm still new at JS so this is all weird to me

Comment: Check the plugin i have attached. Scroll down to the examples and press "run" , the code is displayed above each example. You are requesting for a way to do it in Javascript but there is no way for someone to simply provide directions for such a case in here. It needs a lot of coding. The Plugin i have attached though , on the other hand , is pretty much what you are requesting. It creates a Container with anything you want inside it from Forms , images , Radios , multiple forms , animations , etc.

Comment: Oh yeah... Now I get it... I tried searching for this thing using a lot of other key words but all that popped out we're single object things... It got annoying for about 5 hrs so I asked :/ anyway thank you for the plugin suggestion! Even though I don't like to use plugins maybe I could study this and make my own so thanks again!  :D

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please use the arrows on the left side to rate it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp ?

You can add elements to the body of your web page with javascript.

Comment: no not just one object but a lot.